# SXA Theme's versioncontrol

Tags: sxa

We are currently experimenting with SXA however we have a view difficulties some of you maybe already figured out.

When we want to work with an SXA theme, our current workflow is to keep everything in git and deploy changes automatically through the OTAP environments. This seems rather tricky in SXA, what is your experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully deployed three websites using SXA with the items tracked using Unicorn.

I wrote an [article](https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2017/04/unicorn-serialization-for-sxa-projects.html) discussing how I did this not long ago.

#### Considerations

While there are many things to consider, here are a few I hope the article helps address.

- All code and items are tracked using Unicorn.
- Items under *Home* and the grandchildren of *Data* are excluded from source control, as are the media paths for the tenant. I used transparent sync to include everything and **.gitignore** to prevent accidentally checking in. You may feel the need to track everything but do note that images bloat the repo.
- Track both the serialized theme and the raw version. This is important when using Creative Exchange.
- The configuration I created makes just about everything owned by developers. This includes site settings. Unicorn provides other options.
- SXA includes a bundler, so only be concerned with the transpiling of assets such as SASS.
- Exclude npm files from git.

Your question calls out managing the theme, but consider a solution that works for content and code.